# Vector field problem: solenoidal and irrotational field - find constants

Tags: calculus

I've been stuck on a problem in vector calculus for three weeks now, on divergence and curl. For the vector field $\mathbf{v}$ defined as
$$ 
\mathbf{v} = (x+2y+4z)\mathbf{i} +(2ax+by-z)\mathbf{j} + (4x-y+2z)\mathbf{k},
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are constants. Find $a$ and $b$ such that **v** is both solenoidal and irrotational.

For this problem I've taken the divergence and the curl of this vector field, and found six distinct equations in $a$ and $b$. I've discarded $x, y, z$ and I currently have lots of equations for only 2 unknowns. I'm finding it really hard to find a solution to all the equations simultaneously, partly because there's so many abut also because the equations are a bit complex, involving quadratic terms (so hence a lot of possible unknowns). I'm assuming $a$ and $b$ are real. Can anyone help here? Thank you.

Comment: The two conditions give two linear equations in the unknowns $a$ and $b$. Write down these equations and solve them.

Comment: How did you get quadratics by differentiating linear terms!?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it *has* a right answer. If OP was unable to comprehend it OP must be stuck on it for more than eight years now.

Answer (score 2):

We have

$$\begin{align}
\nabla \times v &= \bigg( \frac{\partial}{\partial y} (4x - y + 2z) - \frac{\partial}{\partial z} (2ax + by - z) \bigg) \vec i - \bigg( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (4x - y + 2z) - \frac{\partial}{\partial z} (x + 2y + 4z) \bigg) \vec j \\
&+ \bigg( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (2ax + by - z) - \frac{\partial}{\partial y} (x + 2y + 4z) \bigg) \vec k\\
&=(-1 - (-1)) \vec i - (4 - 4) \vec j + (2a - 2) \vec k \\
&= (2a - 2) \vec k
\end{align}$$

For this to be irrotational, we require

$$\begin{align}
\nabla \times v &= \vec 0 \\
&= (2a - 2) \vec k \\
\implies a &= 1 \\
\end{align}$$

For solenoidal, we require

$$\begin{align}
\nabla \cdot v &= 0 \\
&= \bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \bigg) \cdot (x + 2y + 4z, 2(1) + by - z, 4x - y + 2z) \\
&= 1 + b + 2 \\
&= 3 + b \\
\implies b&= -3 \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: A should be 1, you have the wrong sign in your simplified expression for the curl

Comment: I did too, I see it. It's too late at night. Thanks for the heads up.